# Delaying Animation on Click Slide Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, slick.js

I have a slick slider that use a fade transition. Each active slide has an animation that scales the background image of the slide. When the slide changes the animation is removed from the slide.

When manually clicking to a new slide the scale jumps back to the default size before the transition finished creating a jump on the image. My question is how do I delay the removal of the animation so I don't get that jump back to the default scale?

Code is below, and you can see an example here: http://tesla.uk-cpi.com/

**JS**

```
// Slider on Home Page
$('.homeSlider').slick({
     draggable: true,
     autoplay: true,
     autoplaySpeed: 7000,
     arrows: false,
     dots: true,
     fade: true,
     speed: 500,
     infinite: true,
     cssEase: 'linear',
     touchThreshold: 100,
     customPaging : function(homeSlider, i) {
        var title = $(homeSlider.$slides[i]).data('title');
        var number = $(homeSlider.$slides[i]).data('index-number');

        return '<a class="pager__item" onClick=reset()><div class="slide-number">'+number+'</div><div class="slide-title">'+title+'</div></a>';
    },
});

$('.slick-active .item').addClass('kenburnseffect');

$('.homeSlider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    $('.item').removeClass('kenburnseffect');
    $('.slick-active .item').addClass('kenburnseffect');
});
```

**CSS**

```
  .item {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

@-webkit-keyframes kenburns {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes kenburns {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout,

```
$('.homeSlider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.item').removeClass('kenburnseffect');
        $('.slick-active .item').addClass('kenburnseffect');
    },1000);
});
```

Here, time delay is given 1000 milli-seconds

Comment: I tried this but I still get the jump when the class is removed when clicking. Ideally the class needs to be removed once the new slide in in place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and never found a good JS solution. One CSS solution I've found that isn't perfect but at least hides the ugly 'jump' when you skip the slide mid-animation is to add this:

```css
.slick-slide[aria-hidden="true"] img {
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

It basically hides the active slide during the fade, so you don't get as much of a blend between the two slides the casual observer probably won't notice or care.

**EDIT** - Found another, better CSS solution. There's a CSS animation property called 'animation-play-state'. Instead of hiding the image during the transition, you can pause it so that it doesn't jump when the current class disappears. However, you do need to make the animation infinite as it'll resume, rather than reset on each slide, so if the user comes back around to them it'll eventually stop. You will also want to make the animation start and end in the same state to loop seamlessly. Code example below:

```
img {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  animation-name: bannerPan;
  animation-duration: 18s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slick-current img {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes bannerPan {
  0% {
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }

  50% {
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```